# MongoDB insert performance with 2nd index

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert about 250 million documents that are each roughly 400 bytes into MongoDB 3.0 with WiredTiger. I need to search on only one short string key, `_user_lower`. Although I'm using WiredTiger now, which is much better than MMAPv1, I did use MMAPv1 first and had similar issues.

My server (a very cheap VPS) has:

- 250 GB magnetic disk
- 1 GB RAM
- 2 GB Swap
- 2.1 GHz single-core CPU

I know that this machine is really slow, and I'm asking it to do something a bit unrealistic. But I'm confused about how it started so fast with one index, and the second just ruined the performance:

I inserted all the data that I had at the time (about 250M rows) *without any index except on `_id`*. This performed very well, considering my awful hardware:

- Approximately **5000 inserts per second** (totally acceptable)
- This rate was nearly constant for the 14 hours hours it took to complete
- The index size on `_id` once complete was nearly 2.5GB. Note that this is more than double my physical RAM.
- The RES of the process didn't exceed 450 MB according to mongostat.
- No swapping
- `top` seemed to indicate that CPU time wasn't all being spent waiting for the disk (so a significant amount was spent in userspace, presumably with WiredTiger in the `snappy` code)

Then I built a (non-unique) index on the only field I need to query by, `_user_lower`. This took 7.7 hours, which is fine since that's a one-time deal. The index ended up being 1.6 GB, which seems really low to me when compared to the `_id` index. The RES went up to about 750 MB.

Then, I downloaded a new data set to load. It was only **102 MB (238 K documents)**. I loaded it in the same way, using `mongoimport`, but this time:

- Only **80 inserts per second (slower at times)**
- RES stayed at around 750 MB
- `top` says almost 100% of the CPU was spent waiting for IO
- Of course, load went through the roof.

I could understand a sizable performance hit, since that index has to be updated. But I didn't expect this much. I've read all over the place that my indexes should fit in RAM, but the performance was great during the initial insert, where the index quickly outgrew my memory.

Can I optimize the `_user_index` index at all? I don't know what this would even mean, but maybe only index the first few characters? I'm definitely willing to halve the query performance in exchange for tripling the insert performance.

**What accounts for the massive performance hit?** How do I fix it without new hardware? I'm not really attached to MongoDB, so alternatives that don't have these performance characteristics are fine. I have an idea that just uses flat files which would probably work but I don't want to write all that code.

Comment: What does the `_id` index look like, i.e. what data type and how is the data distributed?

Comment: It's just this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ (what comes out of the box with MongoDB)

Comment: Well, `ObjectId`s are created monotonically, ever-increasing. That means that keeping the index up-to-date is quite easy, because we're always writing on one end, so to speak. Of course, the B-Tree needs balancing every now and then, but compared to the insertion of random values (names) into the index that is splattered around the disk and can't be kept in RAM, that should lead to a lot less disk reads. And since a single disk read would take about 20 weeks if a main memory ref took 100s (https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375), that alone could be the cause of the trouble.

Comment: @mnemosyn can you expand on that and add it as an answer then I'll accept it? I actually thought they were intentionally random to help with sharding, which I was mistaken about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding new items to a collection, the database will have to keep the index up-to-date. Since the index in MongoDB is a B-Tree by default, that means it will have to insert an item in the tree. While that isn't a particularly expensive operation in the best case, it comes with two potential performance problems:

1. performance jitter: from time to time, the B-Tree bucket might be full, requiring a bucket split and hence a lot more operations than the 'simple' insert
2. the insert destination must be readily available

In this case, the latter is likely to cause trouble: because the insertion of a name hits a random node in the tree (i.e, the name insertion doesn't follow a pattern) and your RAM is smaller than the index, chances are high that the destination must be fetched from disk. Unfortunately, the performance of disk seeks is [orders of magnitude lower than main memory references](https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375). If you're unlucky, the first ref location requires another disk seek such that for a single insert multiple disk reads are required before MongoDB can even *begin* writing. That can take hundreds of milliseconds, with spinning disks or some contention on typical IaaS infrastructure even seconds.

Because ObjectIds are generated monotonically (the timestamp is the most significant part), the insertion always happens at the end and it is possible to keep the destination largely in RAM. Performance jitter, i.e. problem 1 might still be an issue since a bucket split might require a disk seek, but it happens so rarely compared to the first case that it doesn't wreck average performance, which should explain the observed behavior.

Also, when the bucket is filled by a monotonically increasing value, MongoDB will split the bucket when it is 90% filled; with random insertion, splits will happen a lot earlier, at 50%, so the tree is a little more 'dense' in that case.